# Volley Image Loader throws ParseError

Tags: android, image, loader, android-volley

I've met annoying problem using `NetworkImageView`. It throws `ParseError` in `ImageRequest.doParse(NetworkResponse response)` library method.

```
private Response<Bitmap> doParse(NetworkResponse response) {
    byte[] data = response.data;
    BitmapFactory.Options decodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (mMaxWidth == 0 && mMaxHeight == 0) {
        decodeOptions.inPreferredConfig = mDecodeConfig;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, decodeOptions);
    } else {
        // If we have to resize this image, first get the natural bounds.
        decodeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, decodeOptions);
        int actualWidth = decodeOptions.outWidth;
        int actualHeight = decodeOptions.outHeight;

        // Then compute the dimensions we would ideally like to decode to.
        int desiredWidth = getResizedDimension(mMaxWidth, mMaxHeight,
                actualWidth, actualHeight);
        int desiredHeight = getResizedDimension(mMaxHeight, mMaxWidth,
                actualHeight, actualWidth);

        // Decode to the nearest power of two scaling factor.
        decodeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        // TODO(ficus): Do we need this or is it okay since API 8 doesn't support it?
        // decodeOptions.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = PREFER_QUALITY_OVER_SPEED;
        decodeOptions.inSampleSize =
            findBestSampleSize(actualWidth, actualHeight, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
        Bitmap tempBitmap =
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, decodeOptions);

        // If necessary, scale down to the maximal acceptable size.
        if (tempBitmap != null && (tempBitmap.getWidth() > desiredWidth ||
                tempBitmap.getHeight() > desiredHeight)) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap,
                    desiredWidth, desiredHeight, true);
            tempBitmap.recycle();
        } else {
            bitmap = tempBitmap;
        }
    }

    if (bitmap == null) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(response));
    } else {
        return Response.success(bitmap, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
}
```

It throws it because of

> bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, decodeOptions);

returns null. But it **returns null not on all devices.**

I've tested it on :

- HTC **Sensation XE**
- Nexus **5**
- Samsung **S4**
- Samsung **Note**

and only Samsung Note has this error.

**Url** is OK - I can open it in browser (and yes it's an image)
**Data** should be OK as it can be decoded in other devices

`decodeByteArray` documantaion says :

> **Returns**
>   The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded, or, if opts is non->null, if opts requested only the size be returned (in opts.outWidth and opts.outHeight)

I've tried to pass `null` as opts parameter, but it still returns null. So anybody know what is happening here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in Image format. It was **JFIF**. Seems that not all devices supports it. As I had an access to server side I just changed Image there. Other way you need to implement your own decode method to support this format in all devices.

Cheers